# std::map::upper_bound vs std::upper_bound performance

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

In some CP contest (it is important) I have used 2 versions of upper_bound to find upper bound in my `std::map`:

Algorithm upper bound **(1)**:

```
auto itr = std::upper_bound(s.begin(),s.end(), somenumber);

if(itr == s.end() || *itr > somenumber2)
{
//dosth
} else
//dosth2
}
```

std::map::upper_bound **(2)**:

```
auto itr = s.upper_bound(somenumber);

if(itr == s.end() || *itr > somenumber2)
{
//dosth
} else
//dosth2
}
```

Both versions works if I put small input by hand. But when comes to `~500.000` input **(1)** exceeded the time limit (`4 seconds`) but **(2)** do the job in `0.5/4.0 second`. 
I checked at docs [algorithm/upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and [map/upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound) and both have `O(c log(n))` complexity (I think that in both cases `c` should be similar. 
 So the question is - what caused that difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [cppreference page for `std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) says that the number of comparisons done is logarithmic, but it also continues:

> However, for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear.

`std::map` does not have random access iterators and therefore `std::upper_bound` will be allowed to have linear time complexity in the iterator distance due to increments, while `std::map::upper_bound` is required to have logarithmic time complexity in the size of the container.

Comment: I have read that - I thought due to logarithmic time in map::upper_bound there exists some specialization of std::upper_bound for map. Ok, now it's clear and understands why there exists special version of upper_bound in `std::map` and algorithm upper_bound works just in general case (without any additional pieces of information about certain STL structures).

Comment: @mvxxx there are other examples in the standard library of that practice. ex: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) vs. [`std::list::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort).

Comment: @mvxxx I am unsure right now, but there is probably some arcane reason that using the `std::map` specific algorithm for `std::upper_bound` when provided with an `std::map` iterator would make the implementation non-conforming.

Comment: maybe it comes for some kind of philosophy? std::<some_algorithm> from `algorithm` should works in general case and each boost which we can make in certain structures (using extra information about them) should be done as a method of given structure?

Comment: @walnut from my understanding `map::upper_bound` performs a tree search starting from the root node (assuming `map` is implemented as a red-black tree). That is also the reason `map::upper_bound` doesn't accept an iterator pair (it always searches the entire container). `std::upper_bound` is more general and that's why it doesn't use `map::upper_bound`.